# Does SQL Server LIKE opertor with Empty String (%''%) match all non-NULL values in VARCHAR column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL which is executed as part of stored procedure (value provided to LIKE operator is a variable set to empty string):

```
SELECT productCode FROM tblProductCodes WHERE productCode LIKE %''%;
--productCode is a VARCHAR(255) column
```

Is it save to assume that the above query will always return all non-NULL `productCode` entries from the table?

I'm running SQL Server 2008

Comment: Realistically having productcode as varchar column is not a good suggested practice, try and sort out data types.

Comment: Yes, assuming that your query ends up as `productCode LIKE '%%'` or `productCode LIKE '%' + '' + '%'` or `productCode LIKE '%' + @varcontainingemptystring + '%'`.

Comment: Thanks @SalmanA, yes this is exactly what it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a syntax error:

```
WHERE productCode LIKE %''%
```

Presumably you mean:

```
WHERE productCode LIKE '%%'
```

This matches all non-`NULL` values of `productCode`.  `%` is a wildcard that matches 0 or more characters.

If you want to guarantee a code with a certain number of characters, then you can use `_`.  So this ensures that `productCode` has at least two characters:

```
WHERE productCode LIKE '__%'
```